# pyspark SQL DF, join multiple tables, one has no common ID

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following 3 tables:

```
'---- groupedFlightData show(10) -----'
+-----------------+----+------------+
|dest_country_name|year|flight_count|
+-----------------+----+------------+
|      Saint Lucia|2011|         102|
|          Hungary|2014|           2|
|       Guadeloupe|2014|          43|
|          Nigeria|2014|          49|
|             Fiji|2015|          24|
|           Kuwait|2010|          26|
|   Cayman Islands|2011|         251|
|         Paraguay|2011|          85|
|          Austria|2011|          34|
|        Gibraltar|2014|           1|
+-----------------+----+------------+


'---- sumAllTrips -----'
+-----------+
|total_count|
+-----------+
|    2352430|
+-----------+


'---- TPY -----'
+----+----------+
|year|year_count|
+----+----------+
|2012|    422180|
|2014|    436855|
|2013|    417869|
|2011|    428426|
|2015|    453316|
|2010|    422269|
+----+----------+
```

I want to join them all using pyspark SQL and need the resulted table to be:

```
'---- stats show(10) -----'
+-----------+----+------------+-------+----------+
|    Country|year|flight_count|  total|year_count|
+-----------+----+------------+-------+----------+
|Afghanistan|2011|           8|2352430|    390663|
|Afghanistan|2012|           5|2352430|    385290|
|Afghanistan|2010|          11|2352430|    385450|
|    Algeria|2015|           4|2352430|    411966|
|    Algeria|2014|           9|2352430|    398022|
|    Algeria|2013|           2|2352430|    381039|
|     Angola|2015|          15|2352430|    411966|
|     Angola|2014|          13|2352430|    398022|
|     Angola|2011|          13|2352430|    390663|
|     Angola|2012|          12|2352430|    385290|
+-----------+----+------------+-------+----------+
```

I tried the following code:

```
    sqlQuery = spark.sql("""
    SELECT groupedFlightData.dest_country_name AS Country, groupedFlightData.year, groupedFlightData.flight_count , TPY.year_count
    FROM groupedFlightData
    FULL JOIN  TPY ON TPY.year=groupedFlightData.year
    ORDER BY Country
""")
```

Which is incomplete and I can't figure out how to join the third table sumAllTrips with no ID and how to include it into the same query.
My final code must be all using SQL queries, no RDDs or DF based syntax allowed

Comment: for that person who gave me -1...Why?!

Comment: If the answer resolved your issue, kindly **accept** it (otherwise, pls leave feedback on what did not work)

Answer (score 1):

Whan you need is called cartesian join and you can use it with `CROSS JOIN` in spark sql. Your extended query can look like this:

```
sqlQuery = spark.sql("""
    SELECT groupedFlightData.dest_country_name AS Country,
           groupedFlightData.year, 
           groupedFlightData.flight_count, 
           sumAllTrips.total_count AS total, 
           TPY.year_count
    FROM groupedFlightData
    FULL JOIN  TPY ON TPY.year=groupedFlightData.year
    CROSS JOIN sumAllTrips
    ORDER BY Country
""")
```